# Data Connection does not refresh in Excel

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, custom-list, excel, excel-services

I have a SharePoint list; Exported into Excel file and set the property to refresh Data Connection every time the file is opened.

It worked very well in Excel installed on my system but when I uploaded the Excel file on my SharePoint Site then it does not refresh the connection to SharePoint List.

My Excel file contains Charts in it which I need to show on SharePoint using Excel web services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel services will not "refresh" from inside SharePoint.  Another service called "PowerPivot" can be deployed, and this extends excel services and will give you the ability to schedule a refresh of the Excel workbook.  What has to occur is workbook must be opened, refresh the data, then saved back to SharePoint.  That is what the PowerPivot plugin does.  It allows you to specify an account that will act as the user to refresh the data. However it will only refresh once a day at most.

Comment: Is PowerPivot already deployed on SharePoint Online? And can you please explain how can I achieve this with PowerPivot?